# Есть строка, берущаяся из интернета в текстовом формате, которая выглядит примерно так «27,35 руб.»

Tags: python

Как сделать так, чтобы из неё бралось только числовое значение, с которым можно производить математические расчёты? В данный момент, если я пытаюсь их произвести например с первым символом этой строки, (допустим умножение на 2), то он не считает 2*2= 4, а пишет 22, принимая двойку за текст, а не в качестве числа. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Уточните формат строки. Всегда ли она выглядит так? Будет "27,00 руб." или "27 руб."?

Comment: Сделайте индексируемый заголовок для вопроса

Answer (score 0):

```
_s = '23,75 руб.'
print(float(_s.replace(',', '.').replace(' руб.', '')) * 2.0)
```

Но так как существует некоторое недопонимание, то более универсальное решение:

```
import re

_s = '23,75 руб.'
_s = re.sub(r'(?=.*)?[^0-9,]+|^$', '', _s)
_s = _s.replace(',', '.')
_s = float(_s)
print(_s * 2.0)
```

Comment: Можете объяснить, почему регулярка имеет именно такой вид? Почему не просто `[^0-9,]+`, скажем?

Comment: @dIm0n, так вышло

Comment: @icYFTL то есть, вы не можете объяснить?

Comment: Вместо `.*` там было `[а-яА-Я]+` а потом я решил, что лучше вообще все вырезать кроме цифр. И да - очевидно можно `[^0-9,]+`